# How to Convert html template to right to left (RTL) format

Tags: html, right-to-left

How to Convert html template to **right to left** format 
Now I have a normal html template.
to change the template **right to left**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `dir="rtl"` in `HTML` tag like this code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en" dir="rtl">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Shafayat</title>
 <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```